# Wordpress speed slow after .5 million single image post via wp-cli

Tags: images, performance, wp-cli

I am trying to Creat Wordpress website that will contain 10 Million post, such that when i upload a single its become a post with it's own name as title.  and i am importing these images with Wp-cli. now the problem i am facing is that i have uploaded about half a million images and now Wordpress has become slow, its taking too much time to import images. please suggest me any solution for this

Images Importing goes slow down, Server usage only 1%
i am doing this Via WP-cli with this command

```
wp media import ~/Pictures/processed-images-medium/\*\*\/\*.jpg
```

every time when image upload its become a Unique post you can check it at here

```
http://www.wallpaper2k.com/naked-art-first/
```

Comment: You mean the import is slowing down, or that browsing your website is slow? Are you importing all images to a single post? Try to profile it to find the bottleneck. Maybe it's the process of determining the unique slug that's getting slower? Please update your question with more detail to increase the change of someone giving a useful answer.

Comment: i have update the Question please check it now, Thanks

Comment: Try e.g. to log the time for e.g. `wp_insert_post()` and `wp_unique_post_slug()` on your dev install and try to look for suitable hooks for that. The `wp profile` command might also give info on your site.

Comment: Could you please explain it how i can do it?

Comment: You might also get an indication by running those WP functions within the `wp shell` with a timer (search e.g. for microtime in PHP) or e.g. try it with `wp profile eval <php-code>`. You can also look at it from within the wp-admin backend, with a profiling plugin like the Query Monitor and try e.g. to see if it gives any information when you manually upload a file. Note that this site does not favor long comment discussion, so it's recommended to give as much detail in the question to increase the change for someone being able to give a useful answer.

Comment: is there any way to to run website with Database part, its happening because its database is too big

Answer (score 0):

You need to either read more about database optimization or hire a specialist and distribute those posts possibly on multiple database and file servers.
Even if you build a custom solution it would be slow so don't blame WP.